# How to get displayed width of a string?

Tags: c++, unix

When you have non-fixed width characters (such as `\t`) in a string , or escape codes, such as those for ANSI color (such as `\1xb[31m`), these characters add to the `.length()` of an `std::string`, but do not add to the *displayed* length when printed.

Is there any way in C++ to get the displayed width of a string in *nix?

For instance:

```
displayed_width("a\tb") would be 4 if the displayed tab width is 2
displayed_width("\1xb[33mGREEN") would be 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most commonly, a tab asks the terminal program to move the cursor to a column that's a multiple of 8, though many terminal programs let you configure that.  With such behaviour, how much width a tab actually adds depends on where the cursor was beforehand relative to the tab stops.  So, simply knowing the string content is not enough to calculate a printable width without some assumption or insight regarding prior cursor placement and tab stops.

Non-printable codes also vary per terminal type, though if you only need ANSI colour then that's pretty easy.  You can move along the string counting characters; when you see an ESCAPE skip through to the terminating `m`.  Something like (untested):

```
int displayed_width(const char* p)
{
    int result = 0;
    for ( ; *p; ++p)
    {
        if (p[0] == '\e' && p[1] == '[')
            while (*p != 'm')
                if (*p)
                    ++p;
                else
                    throw std::runtime_error("string terminates inside ANSI colour sequence");
        else
            ++result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ahh - I forgot about that behaviour of tabs - very good point. Also, rolling my own string parsing was my fallback plan, but thanks for the starter code.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing built in. The "displayed width" of the tab character is an implementation detail, as are console escape sequences. C++ doesn't care about platform-specific things like that.

Is there something in particular you're trying to do? We may be able to suggest alternatives if we know what particular task you're working on.

Comment: I'm trying to make a generic wrapper around (what is effectively) a string in order to draw an ASCII box around it. The string may contain color escape sequences and tab characters, which I need to know about in order to calculate the correct dimensions of the box.

Comment: This is all system-specific, so standard C++ won't be able to help you. You'll have to roll your own, or find a library online (I'm not aware of anything offhand.)

Answer (score 0):

Not with standard methods to my knowledge. C++ does not know about terminals. 
My guess would be to use NCURSES for that. Dunno if boost has something up the sleeve for that though.

Answer (score 0):

Display length on what device? A console that uses a fixed-width font? A window that uses a proportional font? This is highly device-dependent question. There is no fixed answer. You will have to use the tools associated with the target output device.

Comment: Agreed - it is highly dependent. I was specifically interested in a fixed-width console in *nix. Also, when I was talking about width, I meant character width - so the text being fixed-width is irrelevant.

Comment: When you type input into a comment window the text you type is displayed in a fixed-width font. When you press "Add comment" your text is displayed in a proportional font. "i" takes up a lot less space than does "M".

Comment: You're right - it's not irrelevant, so my previous comment was wrong. I was trying to edit it to correct it, but it was past the 5 minute time limit.